# using antd with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, antd

I'm trying to use ant.design react components with my redux-form, so far it goes something like this:

```
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

.....

<FormItem>
  <Field
     component={Input}
     placeholder="First Name"
     name="name"
  />
</FormItem>
```

seems like `antd` form inputs don't support `name` attribute, they ignore and prevent to pass it down.

`name` attribute is needed for redux-form to be working.

does anyone had success to get these 2 working together? thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to Maxim answer, I had to pass redux-form `props.input` comp to antd Input component.

```
const NewInput = ({
        label,
        labelCol,
        wrapperCol,
        help,
        extra,
        validateStatus,
        hasFeedback = true,
        colon,
        ...rest
}) => {
  return (<FormItem
    label={label}
    wrapperCol={wrapperCol}
    labelCol={labelCol}
    help={help}
    hasFeedback={hasFeedback}
    extra={extra}
    validateStatus={validateStatus}
    colon={colon}
  >
    <Input {...rest.input} />
  </FormItem>);
};
```

Comment: can you please include a tree into your example?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you should not wrap redux-form `Field` component in the antd `Form.Item` component. Instead, you should create your own component:

```
<FormItem>
  <Input/>
</FormItem>
```

and pass this component into the `Field.component`.
However, it does not sound cool, so you should consider using https://github.com/zhdmitry/redux-form-antd. This lib already have set of antd components wrapped in the `Form.Item`, so in your case it is just

```
<Field name="name" component={TextField} />
```

Comment: I added `const NewInput = () => <FormItem><Input /></FormItem>;` and passed it to redux-form Field but it still doesn't connect to redux somehow, maybe I'm missing something? I don't like to use and extra lib and it doesn't support all of the comps